# Formatting JSON before inserting to MongoDB

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

I'm new to MongoDB and I'm still learning so please bear with me.

Let's say I have a document in Mongo with the following form

```
{ 'objName': 
    {  
      'id': 012345678,
      'name': 'someName'
     }
}
```

If I insert this JSON using pyMongo it'll take a default Object ID.
What I'd like to do is to set the

```
    _id = 'id'
```

that is given inside the 'ObjName'.

The problem that I'm facing is that I don't know the value inside 'ObjName' so I need something generic to work regardless of the value inside.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do...  How can you not know the content of the JSON object you are about to write to Mongo?  Since you're writing Python I suggest you show what objects you've got and how you're trying to write them out so far.

Comment: The JSON objects that are going to be inserted are retrieved through an online REST API. The API will return different name for each type of query i send to it so i need something to work ignoring the value inside 'ObjName'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign value to `_id`

```
doc = {'objName': {'id': 12345678,'name': 'someName'}}
doc['_id'] = doc['objName']['id']
collection.insert_one(doc)
```